# Import Python modules with the same name

Tags: python, import, module

I have several Python projects and they all have a `conf` package:

```
/some_folder/project_1/
  conf/
    __init__.py
    some_source_file.py

/another_folder/project_2/
  conf/
    __init__.py
    another_source_file.py
```

For each project, I have created a `.pth` file in the site-packages folder with this contents:

```
.../site-packages/project_1.pth:
import sys; sys.path.append('/some_folder/project_1/')

.../site-packages/project_2.pth:
import sys; sys.path.append('/another_folder/project_2/')
```

I can access modules in `/some_folder/project_1/`:

```
import conf.some_source_file
```

but not the modules in `/another_folder/project_2/`:

```
import conf.another_source_file
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'another_source_file'
```

It looks as if python only searches the first `conf` path underneath any folders in `sys.path`. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python : importing different module with same name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32884206/python-importing-different-module-with-same-name)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. You will need to either rename one of them or turn the project directory into a package and import via that.

Comment: correct. i've actually been doing that all along and now I realize the problem does not seem to be with python itself, but with the mod_wsgi apache module in whose context the second project is running. that's a whole different story of course, so I've posted a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631826/mod-wsgi-import-python-modules-with-the-same-name

Comment: Actually this is solvable using [python - How can I import a module dynamically given the full path? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-can-i-import-a-module-dynamically-given-the-full-path)