# How to pass broker_url from Django settings.py to a Celery service

Tags: django, celery

I have Celery running as a service on Ubuntu 20.04 with RabbitMQ as a broker.

Celery repeatedly restarts because it cannot access the RabbitMQ url (RABBITMQ_BROKER), a variable held in a settings.py **outside** of the Django root directory.

The same happens if I try to initiate celery via command line.

**I have confirmed that the variable is accessible from within Django from a views.py print statement.**

**If I place the RABBITMQ_BROKER variable inside the settings.py within the Django root celery works.**

My question is, how do I get celery to recognise the variable RABBITMQ_BROKER when it is placed in  /etc/opt/mydjangoproject/settings.py?

My celery.py file:

```
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mydjangoproject.settings')

app = Celery('mydjangoproject')

default_config = 'mydjangoproject.celery_config'

app.config_from_object(default_config)
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

My celery_config.py file:

```
from django.conf import settings

broker_url = settings.RABBITMQ_BROKER
etc...
```

The settings.py in /etc/opt/mydjangoproject/ (non relevant stuff deleted):

```
from mydangoproject.settings import *

RABBITMQ_BROKER = 'amqp://rabbitadmin:somepassword@somepassword@webserver:5672/mydangoproject'
etc...
```

My /etc/systemd/system/celery.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=DJANGO_USER
Group=DJANGO_USER
EnvironmentFile=/etc/conf.d/celery
WorkingDirectory=/opt/mydjangoproject

ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} -A $CELERY_APP multi start $CELERYD_NODES \
   --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} \
   --loglevel="${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL}" $CELERYD_OPTS'
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi stopwait $CELERYD_NODES \
    --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} --loglevel="${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL}"'
ExecReload=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} -A $CELERY_APP multi restart $CELERYD_NODES \
    --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} \
    --loglevel="${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL}" $CELERYD_OPTS'
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My /etc/conf.d/celery file:

```
CELERYD_NODES="worker"
CELERY_BIN="/opt/mydjangoproject/venv/bin/celery"
CELERY_APP="mydjangoproject"
CELERYD_CHDIR="/opt/mydjangoproject/"
CELERYD_MULTI="multi"
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --without-heartbeat --without-gossip --without-mingle"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/run/celery/%n.pid"
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n%I.log"
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding the following to /etc/systemd/system/celery.service

```
Environment="PYTHONPATH=/etc/opt/mydjangoproject:/opt/mydjangoproject"
Environment="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to the end of `/etc/opt/mydjangoproject/settings.py` to have celery pick up the correct broker url (casing might vary based on the version of celery you are using):

```
BROKER_URL = broker_url = RABBITMQ_BROKER
```

This will put the configuration in a place where it will be read by the call to celery's `config_from_object` function.

Next, you will also have to add an environment variable to your systemd unit.  Since you are accessing settings as `mydjangoproject.settings`, you have to make the parent of the `mydjangoproject` directory accessible in the PYTHONPATH:

```
Environment=PYTHONPATH=/etc/opt
```

The `PYTHONPATH` provides python a list of directories to try when trying the import.  However, because we have two different directories with the same name that we are using as a single package, [we also have to add the following lines to `/etc/opt/mydjangoproject/__init__.py` and `/opt/mydjangoproject/__init__.py`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936884/python-import-path-packages-with-the-same-name-in-different-folders):

```
import pkgutil
__path__ = pkgutil.extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

Comment: Many thanks 2ps, I have made the changes, but it doesn't seems to work. I have included the changes to my original post, can you please check to see if I have done everything as you expected?