# How do I use both py-readability-metrics and readability-lxml? Import results in name collision. Both ask for "from readability import ..."

Tags: python, import

```
pip install readability-lxml   
pip install py-readability-metrics
```

In python code:

```py
from readability import Document # this for readability-lxml   
from readability import Readability # this for py-readability-metrics
```

The second import overrides the first.
How can I use both?

I tried:

```py
from readability import Document as dcmt   
from readability import Readability as rdbl
```

It made no difference. I did not expect it would help.

I'm using a virtual environment.
I don't want to start changing names etc. in the `venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/` directory without some advice.
What is the recommended approach?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The question relates to importing python modules into a virtual environment. Name collisions can occur and I provide a specific example of such. I am asking if there is a customary way of handling this problem, or for the way others have dealt with it. 
I tried by editing the name of one of the .py modules after it was imported. This did not succeed because other imported modules were accessing it by its original name.
My own current approach is to create a second virtual environment and use the other readability import (from readability import Readability) in the second virtual environment.

Comment: To further clarify.   

https://pypi.org/project/readability-lxml/ indicates: pip install readability-lxml   
and under Usage: from readability import Document   

https://pypi.org/project/py-readability-metrics/ indicates: pip install py-readability-metrics   
and under Usage: from readability import Readability   

The second "from readability import" overrides the first.   
This means both cannot be used in the same environment.   

After some additional research, I think I have stumbled upon what is known as pip import hell.

Answer (score 2):

Generaly: no. There is no beautiful way to do it without renaming packages. You can [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6630415/19162286).

If there are some important reasons why you can't rename library, you can do it with [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly). Here is an example with connecting `asyncio`:

```py
from importlib import util
import sys


spec = util.spec_from_file_location("async_task", "path/to/Lib/asyncio/__init__.py")
foo = util.module_from_spec(spec)
sys.modules["async_task"] = foo
spec.loader.exec_module(foo)

# You can use foo as asyncio
temp = foo.QueueEmpty()
foo.run()
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67692/19162286

Comment: While your answer _may_ answer the OP's question, link-only answers are discouraged [for these reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259). Please update your answer to provide more context. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found that the best way to handle this was to use 2 different virtual environments.

In one environment, install only readability-lxml .
In the second environment install only py-readability-metrics.

"from readability import" in the first environment does not conflict with "from readability import" in the second environment.

The downside is that the my python code now needs to be split up.
I put the results of the readability-lxml processing into a file.
Then I processed the results in that file with py-readability-metrics.

You could argue that splitting up the code this way is actually a good thing.